# surjectivity of a map in Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

This question is from Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch(page-62).

Let $G$ be a profinite group and $H$ be an arbitrary closed subgroup of $G$. For every discrete $H$-module $A$, define 
$M= Ind^H_{G}(A)$ consisting of all continuous maps $x:G\rightarrow A$ such that $x(τσ)=τx(σ)$ for all $τ\in H$.Which is a $G$ module and the action of $\rho \in G$ on $M$ is given by $(\rho x)(\sigma)=x(\sigma \rho).$ There a canonical projection $$ Ind^H_{G}(A) \rightarrow A $$ which takes $x \in Ind^H_{G}(A)$ to $x(1) \in A.$ This is a $H$-module homomorphisim.

> After that, he is calming that the above map takes the $H$-submodule $A^{'}  =
> \lbrace x:G → A ~|~ x(τ ) = 0 ~\forall τ \not\in H \rbrace$ isomorphically onto $A.$ I don't understand how this is possible. Beacuse if $A^{'}$ contains a nonzero element then H has to a open subgroup.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. "Any non-zero map in $A'$ is continuous" well yes, the maps in $A$ are continuous by definition.

Comment: my claim is $A^{'}$ can not contain a non zero map if $H$ is closed but not open.@CaptainLama

Comment: Note that the condition is not that $x$ should be zero exactly on $G\setminus H$. It should just be zero at least on $G\setminus H$.

Comment: A has discrete topology and $x$ is continuous, if you take the inverse of non zero elements you should get an open set contained in H. Then H has to be an open set.@CaptainLama

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should write in your question, so people who read it can clearly see your reasoning. It seems to me that you are right, the result does not work for arbitrary closed subgroups. It's even easier to see if we take $H$ the trivial subgroup.